# Unable to use a Future value - Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I've fetched a json object and deserialized it and then returned it too.

I want to use this in another file.

I'm unable to assign the values that I'm getting in the first step.

Here are all the codes...

**Service**

```
Future getGeoPoints(String accessToken, String tripId) async {
  String requestUrl;

  var response = await get(
    Uri.parse(requestUrl),
    headers: {
      'Authorization': "Bearer $accessToken",
    },
  );

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    Map<String, dynamic> responseBody = json.decode(response.body);
    GetGeoPoints geoPoints = GetGeoPoints.fromJson(responseBody);
    List listOfGeoPoints = [];
    for (var geoPoint in geoPoints.geoPoints) {
      listOfGeoPoints.add(
        {
          'latitude': geoPoint.latitude,
          'longitude': geoPoint.longitude,
          'timestamp': geoPoint.timeStamp,
        },
      );
    }
    // print('List of geo points: ' + '$listOfGeoPoints');
    return listOfGeoPoints;
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load data from server');
  }
}
```

**File where I need the above values**

```
List routeCoordinates;

Future<void> getValues() async {
    getGeoPoints(widget.accessToken, widget.tripId)
        .then((value) => routeCoordinates = value);
  }
```

When I run the app, routeCoordinates is null but when I hotreload, it contains the value.

I want to have the values as soon as the screen starts. What is the right way to assign the values here?

I've also tried this:

```
routeCoordinates = getGeoPoints...
```

It throws error..

Please help.. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

The function `getGeoPoints()` is an asynchronous one. But on the other file, you are not using the `await` keyword, instead you are using `then()`. So your code is not waiting for that function to return value.

Try using below code,

```
List routeCoordinates;

Future<void> getValues() async {
    routeCoordinates = await getGeoPoints(widget.accessToken, widget.tripId);
 }
```

Let us know how it went.

Comment: I've even tried this. The thing is `routeCoordinates` is getting values later and my build is throwing error to have it as null during build.. routeCoordinates is getting value after the build is done..

Comment: I'm calling `getValues()` inside `init()`

Comment: Well, can you please add the error to your post please?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html%27) to define a behaviour depending on the state of the request. You'll be able to tell the widget what to return while your app is waiting for the response to your request. You can also return a specific widget if you get an error(if your user is offline, for example).

Edit: I've linked the official docs but give [this article](https://medium.com/swlh/flutter-futurebuilder-383b6ed63f18) a read if it's not clear enough.